# Access denied from Google search

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I've a little problem.

Sometimes I get the error "Access denied" when searching for a random keyword.

It looks like this: [image]

Here is the code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // no headers in the output
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // output to variable
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $loginpassw);

// Download the given URL, and return output
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Can we have some code?

Comment: I'm just using a simple cURL call with a private proxy. Nothing more fancy than that.
And the proxy is working fine, because it checks a lot of other keywords without problems

Comment: Without any code, it'll be harder to help you.

Comment: There you go: http://pastebin.com/J5QRxcW4

Comment: Maybe this is the distant website you're `cURLing` that is preventing you from connecting to it (too much)?